# On Apple Silicon: ruby-build: definition not found: 3.0.0

Tags: ruby, apple-silicon, asdf-vm

When I try to install the latest ruby (3.0.0), it fails with:

`ruby-build: definition not found: 3.0.0`

Clearly, [ruby 3 has been released more than a month ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/), so I'm guessing the team is running into problems building/packaging it for Apple Silicon (M1) or no one's had the bandwidth to do so yet. How would I follow up on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASDF users, try `asdf plugin update ruby` then `asdf install ruby the_ruby_version_here`

Comment: This was the issue. The asdf plugin was out of date and was unaware of a new version I specified that had just released a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `brew update && brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build`? [That may help you get the latest available version of Ruby](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#upgrading-with-homebrew). You can try `rbenv install --list` to see what you have available.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solution but when I try this it helps me.

Update Package Index: Start by updating the package index to ensure you install the latest versions of software packages.

```
sudo apt update
```

Install Dependencies: Ensure you have the necessary dependencies installed for rbenv and Ruby.

```
sudo apt install -y git curl libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev autoconf bison build-essential libyaml-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev
```

Clone rbenv Repository: Use git to clone the rbenv repository into your home directory (or another location of your choice).

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

Add rbenv to PATH: Add rbenv to your PATH so that you can use it globally.
You can do this by adding the following lines to your shell configuration
file (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, or similar).

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Don't forget to reload the shell configuration after adding these lines.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Install rbenv Plugins (Optional): Optionally, you can install some useful rbenv plugins. Two popular ones are `ruby-build`, which provides an rbenv-install command to compile and install different versions of Ruby, and rbenv-vars, which allows you to set global and per-project environment variables.

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars
```

Verify Installation: You can verify that rbenv is set up correctly by running:

```
rbenv --version
```

This command should output the version of rbenv you have installed.

Install Ruby: For example, to install Ruby 3.1.0:

```
rbenv install 3.1.0
```

After installing, you can set this version as the global default or use it locally in specific directories.

```
rbenv global 3.1.0
```

And also add this line in the `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: The OP was asking about installation on MacOS, where `apt install` won't work. The first commands should be replaced by `brew install rbenv ruby-build` in order to answer the original question.